# Selection in two lists with UUID in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have simplified my code to show my problem:

```
struct ListItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var sel1: UUID?
    @State var sel2: UUID?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            List([ListItem(name: "Item 1"), ListItem(name: "Item 2"), ListItem(name: "Item 3")], selection: $sel1) { item in
                Text(item.name)
            }
            List([ListItem(name: "Item 1"), ListItem(name: "Item 2"), ListItem(name: "Item 3")], selection: $sel2) { item in
                Text(item.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The selection of an item works, but if I have selected an item in one list and if I then select an item in the other list, the selection of the first list disappears.

Interestingly, it works when I don't use UUID, for example like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var sel1 = ""
    @State var sel2 = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            List(["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"], id: \.self, selection: $sel1) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
            List(["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"], id: \.self, selection: $sel2) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just copy-pasted your code on a new iOS project and this seems to work as expected, State gets retained even when selecting from both lists.

Comment: Or could you clarify what you mean by selection? With the code as is there is no visual feedback when you select anything.

Comment: @vicegax, the selected items should remain highlighted, but they don’t because the UUIDs change when the view is updated.

Answer (score 1):

What I think is happening, is that the view can get re-generated many times as it sees fit to do.
So whenever that happens the `UUID` of the `ListItem(...)` are changed/regenerated and
seems to confuse the `List`. If you use the following approach to have a stable `list` of `ListItem`,
the problems do not show in my tests.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var sel1: UUID?
    @State var sel2: UUID?
    
    let list1 = [ListItem(name: "Item 1"), ListItem(name: "Item 2"), ListItem(name: "Item 3")]
    let list2 = [ListItem(name: "Item 1"), ListItem(name: "Item 2"), ListItem(name: "Item 3")]
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            List(list1, selection: $sel1) { item in
                Text(item.name)
            }
            List(list2, selection: $sel2) { item in
                Text(item.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The view will be updated when any @State var changes, so selecting from a list will cause both lists to be regenerated with new UUIDs which will not match the currently selected IDs. The second example works because the ids are based on the items themselves and remain the same when the lists are regenerated.